# Double elements of a list with specific indices stored in another list

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
L=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

and a list of indices of the elements that should be doubled, for example:

```
dbl_indices = [0, 2, 5]
```

which should turn my list into:

```
[20, 20, 60, 40, 50, 120, 70, 80, 90]
```

Besides iterating in a `for`-loop over the list of indices, what is another, more Pythonic way of doing that?

Comment: You're apparently [already aware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77814908/3001761) of list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Besides iterating in a for-loop over the list of indices, what is another, more Pythonic way of doing that?

There is no way more Pythonic than that loop.

```
for i in dbl_indices:
    L[i] *= 2
```

Answer (score -1):

This is solution is more elegant

```
[x * 2 if i in dbl_indices else x for i, x in enumerate(L)]
```